# Probabilities: Why does this not yield multinomial logistic regression expression?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

***Update:***  The formula

```
Exp[a]/(Exp[a] + Exp[b] + Exp[c])
```

results from using `ExtremeValueDistribution` rather than `GumbelDistribution` as originally stated.

***End of Update***

Evaluating the following command:

```
Probability[(x > y ) && (x > z), {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
   ProductDistribution[GumbelDistribution[a, 1], 
    GumbelDistribution[b, 1], GumbelDistribution[c, 1]]]
```

yields:

> ```
> > (E^(2 a) (E^(a + b) + E^(a + c) + 2 E^(b + c)))/((E^a + E^b) (E^a + E^
> > c) (E^(a + b) + E^(a + c) + E^(b + c)))
> ```

shouldn't it be:

```
exp[a]/(exp[a] + exp[b] + exp[c])
```

Binary Logit works fine, however:

```
Probability[
 x > y, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  ProductDistribution[GumbelDistribution[a, 1], 
   GumbelDistribution[b, 1]]]
```

yielding

```
E^a/(E^a + E^b)
```

Comment: Why do you think `exp[a]/(exp[a] + exp[b] + exp[c])` is the answer?  And by the way, what is MNL and why do you think every potential helper would know what it stands for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Also, it works fine for the binary logit

Probability[
 x > y, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
  ProductDistribution[GumbelDistribution[a, 1], 
   GumbelDistribution[b, 1]]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't yield that formula because it shouldn't.  Simulations can provide simple and direct checks:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;
nsim = 1000000;
x = RandomVariate[GumbelDistribution[a, 1], nsim];
y = RandomVariate[GumbelDistribution[b, 1], nsim];
z = RandomVariate[GumbelDistribution[c, 1], nsim];

N[Total[Boole[#[[1]] > #[[2]] && #[[1]] > #[[3]]] & /@ 
    Transpose[{x, y, z}]]/nsim]
(* 0.053482 *)

N[(E^(2 a) (E^(a + b) + E^(a + c) + 2 E^(b + c)))/((E^a + E^b) (E^a + E^c) (E^(a + b) + E^(a + c) + E^(b + c)))]
(* 0.0533853 *)

N[Exp[a]/(Exp[a] + Exp[b] + Exp[c])]
(* 0.0900306 *)
```